# Media Player MPMediaItemArtwork Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I seem to be getting a memory leak when getting the album artwork for the currently playing item with this code:

```
MPMediaItem *playingItem = self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem;
MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [playingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
```

I have tried [artwork release]; even though I didn't alloc artwork but I am still getting a leak. Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: That is very little code to work on, you must be allocating more memory elsewhere in the application that makes this go over the top.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that the MPMediaItemArtwork is causing the leak. Instruments listed the leaked objects as MPMediaItemArtwork and MPMediaItemArtworkInternal.

For what it's worth, [artwork release] seems to decrease the leaking and removing the artwork code completely kills the leak.